# Rails: Displaying a nested list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a property listing site with the following relationship structure

```
Region has_many :cities
City has_many :investor_cities
City has_many :investors through: :investor_cities

Investor has_many :investor_cities
Investor has_many :cities through: :investor_cities
```

An investor_city records cities that an investor prefers to buy in. It will be used to match properties with investors.

In the show view for an investor, I want to show cities by region that they are interested in.

In the controller

```
@regions = Region.all
```

In the view

```
<% @regions.each do |r| %>
<p><%= r.name %></p>
<ul>
    <% r.cities.each do |c| %>
    <% @inv_cty = InvestorCity.find_by_city_id_and_investor_id(c.id, @investor.id) %>
        <% if @inv_city %>
            <%= @inv_city.city.name %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

However no investor_cities are rendered (despite there being two in the database).

I also tried this:

```
r.cities.investor_cities.each do...
```

But got this error.

```
undefined method `investor_cities' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_City:0x007fb47e09b4d0>
```

Am at a bit of a loss so any ideas would be great. Thanks.

**Edit - the below has worked. I would love to know how to do it a bit cleaner however. Thanks**

```
<% @regions.each do |r| %>
<p><%= r.name %></p>
<ul>
    <% r.cities.each do |c| %>
        <% c.investor_cities.each do |ic| %>
            <% if ic.investor_id == @investor.id %>
                <li><%= ic.city.name %> <%= ic.investor.id %></li>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `r.cities.investor_cities` fails because `investor_cities` is an association off of a single `City` instance, not the collection.

Comment: Your `has_many...through` association does not seem to be correct.  You should have `City has_many :investors, through: :investor_cities` and `Investor has_many :investors, through: :investor_cities`

Comment: @vee Correct - that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use `r.cities.investor_cities.each do...`, 
try using `r.cities.select('investor_cities').where(investor_id: @investor.id).each do ...`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I got this error when I tried your approach SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: investor_cities: SELECT investor_cities FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."region_id" = ? AND "cities"."investor_id" = 1